# Attribute Error API for reading humidity data from external API

Tags: python, api, class

I want to read to humidity data from the API but I keep getting an atribute error.
Anybody can help, I am new to coding and python.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users...HidenForPrivacy", line 27, in <module>
    test.current_humidity()
  File "C:\Users...HidenForPrivacy", line 20, in current_humidity
    response = requests.get(self.url)
AttributeError: 'humidity' object has no attribute 'url'


    
import requests
import json
class humidity():
    def init(self,humidity, url):
        self.humidity = humidity
        self.api_key = "hiddenforprivacy"
        self.lat = "53.5502"
        self.lon = "9.9920"
        self.url = url

    def current_humidity(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        self.url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=%s&lon=%s&appid=%s&units=metric" % (self.lat, self.lon, self.api_key)
        self.humidity = data["current"]["humidity"]
        print(humidity)

test = humidity()
test.current_humidity()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not yet set any value to self.url

When you call `test = humidity()`, you do not call the `init(self, humidity, url)` method, but the empty `__init__(self)` method (the constructor in Python is called `__init__`). So there the url is not set.

In your code you do set the url in line 22 `self.url = "https://api.openweath...`, but that happens after you already called `response = requests.get(self.url)`.

One solution might be to put the line `self.url = "https://api.openweath...` before `response = requests.get(self.url)`